# Update and Use redux state in sibling react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component called `<App/>`, it is a parent component with two children inside it i.e `<Header/>` and `<Main/>`
So the things looks like this

```
<App>
 <Header/>
 <Main />
<App/>
```

When my Header component mounts I set some redux state inside `componentDidMount()`
Then I tried to use that state in my `<Main/>` `componentDidMount()` but my state is always empty in Main component however I already set that in Header component.

Comment: I would say that your `<Main/> componentDidMount()` executes before you change the state in the `<App />` component. Maybe you should make use of `componentDidUpdate` within `<Main/>`.

Comment: Have you connected the `Main` component to the redux-store?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Yes, I did

Comment: are you doing a network call inside the `componentDidMount()` in `<Header />` to fetch the data and set that in the redux state ?

Comment: @Waeez I suggest you show the code for both header and main components where you're setting and accessing the redux state.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Yes, I am making a request to server

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing component state and store state.

You need to use `react-redux` `connect` or `useSelector` / `useDispatch` to connect both components with your store state.

Also you would need an `<Provider store={store}></Provider>` to provide the store context to your components.

You should really read the [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start) and [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) documentation, to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `componentDidMount()` in `< Main />` component try using  `componentDidUpdate()` to check the state.